# As a string column, I've constructed the query that I want to run. How can I execute it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

All of my tables in the `DIM` schema share a bit column called `USER_CHECKED`. With an agent job, I want to output (I don't particularly care where/what to) the name of each table in the schema and the number of times `USER_CHECKED` has the value `0`. Before I can write this agent job, I need to write the underlying query. The natural solution is to use `sp_MSforeachtable`, but that's unsupported. Instead, I've done something like this

```
USE [MY-DB]
SELECT
  TABLE_CATALOGUE,
  CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN [USER_CHECKED] = 0 THEN 1 END) FROM MY-DB.DIM.', 'TABLE_CATALOGUE') AS TO_RUN
FROM
  information_schema.tables
WHERE
  TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DIM'
```

As a result, the `TO_RUN` column contains exactly what query I want to run. However, I've got no idea how to run it. In principle, I could use a cursor, but they're usually a terrible idea. Is there an alternative way to "execute" this column?

Comment: *How can I execute it?* - Maybe look at [Execute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)? What part of your query takes care of the `has the value 0`?

Comment: @Stu I had that in mind, but I'm under the impression that they'd need to be procedures before that would work.

Comment: where did you obtain that impression?

Comment: @Stu Sorry about the '0' part. Will correct. Tried to be too smart with bits.

As for the impression, every tutorial that I saw for the topic of "execute the contents of each row" referred to executing *procedures* even when I specifically searched for executing *queries*.

Comment: It looks like you're half way there, you need to construct your dynamic SQL in its entirety to include the table name and [probably] insert the results into another table which you can later query.

Comment: @Stu That's trivial. Just move a bit of the `SELECT` into the dynamic SQL and maybe `INSERT` In to a `'#temptable`. The only thing that stops me is my lack of knowledge on how to execute this query once for each row. I'll write the `WHILE` loop if I need to, but any pattern that avoids loops and cursors in SQL is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this is to build a single string to execute with a combination of `concat` and `string_agg` to build a single query that unions your individual selects for each table.

You could then optionally include an `insert into` to have the results inserted somewhere.

It's preferable to use the system tables over the information schema views.

The basic idea which you will probably want to tweak is as follows - obviously untested for your environment:

```
declare @Sql nvarchar(max);

select @Sql = String_Agg(Convert(varchar(max),
    Concat(
        'select '
        , QuoteName(t.[name], '''')
        , ' as SourceTable, count(case when USER_CHECKED = 0 then 1 end) User_CheckedIsZero from ' 
        , QuoteName(t.[name])
    )), ' union all ' + char(13)) -- Includes return so print output is readable
from sys.tables t
where Schema_Name(t.schema_id) = 'DIM' and t.[type] = 'U' and t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    and exists (select * from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.[name]='USER_CHECKED');


print @Sql;
-- exec(@Sql);
```